# how can i enable location permission in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to get location permission in electron, and i have tried using the ("setPermisionRequestHandler" in session) but it seems not to be working, what am i doing wrong? here is it:

```
session
    .fromPartition("some-partition")
    .setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback) => {
      const url = webContents.getURL();

      if (permission === "geolocation") {
        // Approves the permissions request
        callback(true);
      }
      // Verify URL
      if (!url.startsWith("https://puram.com")) {
        // Denies the permissions request
        return callback(false);
      }
    });
```

Comment: *"but it seems not to be working"* How exactly did you determine that? What happened?

Comment: Nothing actually happened, my console was not affected. My aim is to get a dialog that shows "Ask(default), allow or block location , if there is any other way please how do i go about it?

Comment: did you solve this issue?